# Asserting on data that is derived from a previous step

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

When a piece of data that I want to assert on in a later test is derived from an earlier step, is there an accepted method of storing and recalling that data later on in the scenario?

For example:

```gherkin
Scenario: Recently viewed product
    Given I am on a product category page
    And I click on the first product
    When I am on a product category page
    Then the recently viewed products should list the product I just viewed
```

On the step `And I click on the first product` can I somehow persist the product name so that I can assert that I am actually seeing that product in the last step? The reason I can't specify an actual product name in the feature file is that this could and will become out of sync with live product data.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason to not use class fields to store that values?

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely up to you how you implement this. The simplest way is in your "I click on the first product" step definition store the clicked product information in a static variable (or as a global variable) and then use it in "the recently viewed products should list the product I just viewed" step to verify it's present.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values you need to persist between steps as FeatureContext class properties.
Don't forget to clear them when the Scenario ends, or before each new Scenario.